# Why are my SHA256 sums different?

Tags: c, checksum, glib

I am using glib to generate SHA256 checksums.  It seemed to be working fine, but when I verified the output using sha256sum I got different results.  Any ideas what is going on?

```
char* createChecksumString(const char* buffer) {
    //Create SHA256 checksum using glib
    gchar* checksum = g_compute_checksum_for_string(G_CHECKSUM_SHA256,
        buffer, -1);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    printf("%s\n", checksum);

    .
    .
    .
}

.
.
.

const char* msg = "Hello SHA256";
char* checksum = createChecksumString(msg);
```

The code above produces:

> Hello SHA256
>
> 70725d0f78cb0967c0e5171f733619712d239e28f2d279e4b3c3ed97f7456fa3

sha256sum produces a different output.  See below:

> echo "Hello SHA256" | sha256sum
>
> e32bd03f46f51d4a5c903429fea1c31032d8d7aa689c764141b7cebd74f4e140

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`echo "Hello SHA256"` prints a newline.

Try with `echo -n "Hello SHA256" | sha256sum`.

Comment: +1, beat me to it. You can [verify this online](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) as well.

Comment: Well, that was simple.  Thanks.